# Cotton Candy grapes (wine)

Tags: taste, wine

Has any attempt been made to produce wine(s) using [Cotton Candy Grapes](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cotton_Candy_grapes)? (Also curious what such a wine would taste like.)

Answer (score 3):

I'm sure someone has tried already. They would taste much like they do when you eat them fresh, so probably a lot like cotton candy. BUT, these are eating grapes and not wine grapes. It would take some effort to make a drinkable wine out of them. Eating grapes have rather thick skins and pulpy flesh which doesn't make it easy to get the juice out. If you got past that hurdle and got a decent amount of juice, they would be too low in sugar and the acid content would also be too low. You could adjust with sugar and acid. Wine grapes are much sweeter than table grapes (which is hard to imagine but they are super sweet when you eat them) and have much higher acids and of course seeds which table grapes do not have seeds.

It's interesting to note that these guys have [created several new grape varieties](https://grapery.biz/index.php/our-grapes) with different flavor.

Comment: Of course the sugars & acids would have to be adjusted but I doubt that should be such an obstacle for expert vintners. IAE, helpful input.